# Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception;

Tags: spring-boot

It was previously on spring boot 1.5 and I am migrating to spring boot 2.0.1. I'm getting the following errors:

> Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataGeneratorFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataGeneratorFilter' defined in class path resource [security/securityContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator#1dc0c635' of type [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator#1dc0c635': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSamlWebSSOFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'samlWebSSOProcessingFilter' defined in class path resource [security/securityContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'samlAuthenticationProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'samlAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUDetails' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'empDataService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empDataService' defined in file [D:.........\EmpDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeSearchRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource ............../ElasticSearchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationError: org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress

gradle.build:

```
compile "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.5.0"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.1.0.Final"
compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:${liquibase_core_version}") {
    exclude(module: 'jetty-servlet')
}
compile "com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j:${liquibase_slf4j_version}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

Comment: so what's your question? If you need some help with debugging, please provide a [mcve] and specify where/when exactly you get the errors

Comment: I am not able to understand what is the main cause of above error. It is of elastic or something else. I am migrating my old spring boot 1.5 project to 2.0.1.

Comment: well, you have to provide some code which reproduces the error, how do you expect us to help otherwise? If you don't understand the source, divide and conquer

Comment: Hi , i just want some clue, why this error is coming, means dependency incompatibility is issue??